# call method with parameters java

Tags: java

I looked and could not find anything like what I am wanting to do. I have a method with 3 parameters that I need to call from my main method. I've tried everything I have leaned in class so far, but I cannot fig this out. this is for  my Programming in Java Course. Here is what I need to call from my main method:

```
import java.util.*;// for scanner
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Grades {

//Homework, exam1, and exam2 weights
static double homeworkWeight;
static double examOneWeight;
static double examTwoWeight;

//Homework
static int homeworkNumberOfAssignments;
static int homeworkAssignment1Score;
static int homeworkAssignment1Max;
static int homeworkAssignment2Score;
static int homeworkAssignment2Max;
static int homeworkAssignment3Score;
static int homeworkAssignment3Max;
static int homeworkSectionsAttended;
static int homeworkSectionsAttendedTotal;
static int homeworkSectionsAttendedMax;
double homeworkTotalPoints;
double homeworkMaxPoints;
double homeworkWeightedScore;

//Exam1
static int examOneScore;
static int examOneCurve;
static double examOneMaxPointsAvailable;
double examOneWeightedScore;

//Exam2
static int examTwoScore;
static int examTwoCurve;
static double examTwoMaxPointsAvailable;
double examTwoWeightedScore;

//Grades
static double courseGrade;
static double grade;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    showIntro();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Homework and Exam 1 weights? ");
    homeworkWeight = console.nextInt();
    examOneWeight = console.nextInt();
    examTwoWeight = 100 - homeworkWeight + examOneWeight;
    System.out.println("Using weights of " + homeworkWeight + " " + examOneWeight + " " + examTwoWeight);
    homework();
    System.out.println("");
    exam1();
    //System.out.println("");
    //exam2();
    //System.out.println("");
    //courseGrade(courseGrade; double homeworkWeightedScore; double examOneWeightedScore; double examTwoWeightedScore;);
    double d = courseGrade(homeworkWeightedScore, examTwoWeightedScore, examTwoWeightedScore);
    System.out.println("");
}//

//Shows the intro to the program to the user.
public static void showIntro() {

    System.out.println("This program accepts your homework scores and");
    System.out.println("scores from two exams as input and computes");
    System.out.println("your grades in the course.");
}

public static void homework() {

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Homework:");
    System.out.print("Number of assignments? ");
    homeworkNumberOfAssignments = console.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Assignment 1 score and max? ");
    homeworkAssignment1Score = console.nextInt();
    homeworkAssignment1Max = console.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Assignment 2 score and max? ");
    homeworkAssignment2Score = console.nextInt();
    homeworkAssignment2Max = console.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Assignment 3 score and max? ");
    homeworkAssignment3Score = console.nextInt();
    homeworkAssignment3Max = console.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Sections attended? ");
    homeworkSectionsAttended = console.nextInt();
    homeworkSectionsAttendedTotal = homeworkSectionsAttended * 4;
    homeworkSectionsAttendedMax = 20;

    //Calculating total points earned
    double totalPoints = homeworkAssignment1Score + homeworkAssignment2Score + homeworkAssignment3Score + homeworkSectionsAttendedTotal;

    //Calutaing the max points available to be earned
    double maxPoints = homeworkAssignment1Max + homeworkAssignment2Max + homeworkAssignment3Max + homeworkSectionsAttendedMax;

    //Formatting with DecimalFormat to remove the decimal and 0 when displaying
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
    System.out.println(("Total points = ") + df.format(totalPoints) + " / " + df.format(maxPoints));

    //Calculating the weighted score by dividing totalPoints by maxPoints and then multiplying times homeworkWeight
    double homeworkWeightedScore = ((totalPoints / maxPoints) * homeworkWeight);

    //Printing out weighted score and rounding to the nearest hundreth with Math.round
    System.out.println("Weighted score = " + Math.round(homeworkWeightedScore * 100.0) / 100.0);

}

public static void exam1() {

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Exam 1:");
    System.out.print("Score? ");
    examOneScore = console.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Curve? ");
    examOneCurve = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Total points = " + examOneScore + " / " + examOneCurve);
    examOneMaxPointsAvailable = 100;
    double examOneWeightedScore = ((examOneScore / examOneMaxPointsAvailable) * examOneWeight);
    System.out.println("weighted score = " + Math.round(examOneWeightedScore * 100.0) / 100.0);

}

public static void exam2() {

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Exam 2:");
    System.out.print("Score? ");
    examTwoScore = console.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Curve? ");
    examTwoCurve = console.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Total points = ");
    System.out.println("weighted score = ");

}


  public double courseGrade(double homeworkWeightedScore, double   examOneWeightedScore, double examTwoWeightedScore) {

     return homeworkWeightedScore + examOneWeightedScore + examTwoWeightedScore;
 }
```

}

Comment: is this method in the same class as the main method ?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. You clearly haven't tried *everything*, but we don't know what you *have* tried, so we can't help you with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple factors missing from your question that makes me unable to completely answer them, but:

Is the courseGrade method in a separate class or in the same class as your `public static void main` method?

Yes: Create a new instance of the separate class by doing: `public SeparateClass instance = new SeparateClass();` inside of `public static void main`

After that, call this from your `main` method: `double grade = instance.courseGrade(homeworkWeightedScore, examTwoWeightedScore, examTwoWeightedScore);`

No: Make the courseGrade method static, you can't call a non-static method from a static method (replace `public double courseGrade` with `public static double courseGrade`). After that, inside of your `main` method, do this: `double d = courseGrade(homeworkWeightedScore, examTwoWeightedScore, examTwoWeightedScore);`

I hope this helps.